# USB destination read only

Tags: usb

I am trying to send files into USB verbatim 4GB,  completely empty, and I receive this messege:
The destination is read only. I have formatted the USB but when I try to change the permission from Read only into Read and write then, that option is not working. 
  No file is available to transfer from my laptop into the VERBATIM USB. Same with other USB memo sticks. 
I have Laptop brand Dell inspirion 15, 3000 series, ram 3,8 GiB, processor Intel® Core™ i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4, OS - Ubuntu 16,04 LTS 64 bit, graphic – Intel.

Please send me solution how to send files into USB and how to change the permission?

Comment: I had the same problem but mine occurred mainly after formatting. I would not get the paste option in Nautilus, plugging the disk out and plugging it in sorted the problem for me. You could try that.

Comment: Should normally be R/W. What says `mount`? A disk can be mounted R/O if it has errors. Anything in /var/log/syslog when you insert the drive?

Comment: Thanks for you answers and here what i got. I did format to the USB and i had the same problem. I could not transfer any file from laptop into USB, jpg, docx, pdf...Few days later it was ok. I did not do anything , it just working by it self. My only explanation is that possible i had some virus in the laptop and after few updates, automaticaly, it erased the virus and it is working right now. Again, thanks for your answers.